# Repeat same match rules

Tags: fluentd

I have following `fluent.conf`.

Here I have same rules for two match patterns: `admin`, `content`.

The only difference is `path` parameter - it contains match patterns.

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>
<match admin>
  @type copy
   <store>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/log/admin.*.log
    time_slice_format %Y.%m.%d-%H.%M
    time_slice_wait 1m
    time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    compress gzip
    format json
  </store>
</match>
<match content>
  @type copy
   <store>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/log/content.*.log
    time_slice_format %Y.%m.%d-%H.%M
    time_slice_wait 1m
    time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    compress gzip
    format json
  </store>
</match>
```

I want to avoid duplication in `match` blocks.

**My question is:** Is there method to define two patterns: `admin`, `content` and make for them singe match block something like this:

```
<match %pattern_name%>
  @type copy
   <store>
    @type file
    path /fluentd/log/%pattern_name%.*.log
    time_slice_format %Y.%m.%d-%H.%M
    time_slice_wait 1m
    time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
    compress gzip
    format json
  </store>
</match>
```